# Pan is not stay at same place after zooming?

Tags: flutter

i am trying to make pan and zoom image, where pivot zoom is always in center of canvas. the zoom is work as expected.

```
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double radius = size.width / 2.0;
    canvas.translate(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    canvas.scale(zoom);
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(offset.dx, offset.dy), radius, Paint());
  }
```

the problem is when panning(translate), the cursor (touch) not stay at same place as image after doing zoom in or zoom out.

full code :
https://dartpad.dev/1cb2f80034dbf6f5fee4bf95382a5fc2?

Comment: check https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/lib/matrix_gesture_detector.dart and https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/example/lib/custom_painter_demo.dart

Comment: @pskink yes that it. thanks. hi my math is not good, could you explain the idea behind it ?

Comment: the idea is to use `Matrix` object and  `Canvas.transform()` method instead of `Canvas.scale()` / `Canvas.translate()`

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
canvas.drawCircle(Offset(offset.dx, offset.dy), radius, Paint());
```

to this

```
canvas.drawCircle(Offset(offset.dx/zoom, offset.dy/zoom), radius, Paint());
```

Comment: if i do that, the zoom pivot is not at center canvas but at image itself .

Comment: You are right. But without it, the pan is also not right, as it does not move the circle by the right distance.